# How to refresh database formula through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an xls sheet which has formulae to fetch data through a database. To get the data, I go to the top ribbons in xls, click on the database ribbon and then click refresh. The xls shortcut to get the data is ALT Y1RS

Can somebody please help me tell how can I write a VBA code so that ALT Y1RS is pressed in xls.

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? In Excel 2007 and higher you need to save the file as .xlsm to be able to do this. Apart from that, have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: I have xls 2010 version and the file format in xlsm. I tried recording a macro but it doesnt write any line.I need to write ALT Y1RS in VBA window.

Comment: Hi i am new to vba too. Is it you want to refresh? You may do Sendkey "^%{F5}"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below piece of code

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This will re-calculate all the equation calculation in the workbook.